# Regex to capture group of words after one character but separated by another

Tags: regex, pcre

I am trying to capture all sub strings after the pipe character (`|`) separated by the hyphen character (`-`). Specifically, I am after these groups of words without preceding or trailing whitespaces:

1. `Status`
2. `Bitmask Flag`
3. `Another Bitmask Flag`

From the following string:

```
Controller | Status - Bitmask Flag - Another Bitmask Flag
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following pattern:

```
(?<=\| |- )[a-zA-Z ]+\b
```

- `(?<=\| |- )` Positive lookbehind for `\` or `-` followed by whitespace.
- `[a-zA-Z]+` Alphabetic characters, one or more
- `\b` Word boundary.

Comment: Thank you. I built on your answer to ignore any additional whitespace (incase tabs or double spaces are encountered) and capture all word characters (incase digits are encountered): (?<=\||-)(?:\s+)([\w\s]+\b)